Как написать трейт для user-defined типа?
Как написать трейт is_user_defined?
class A;
enum B;
static_assert(is_user_defined_v<A> == true);
static_assert(is_user_defined_v<B> == true);
static_assert(is_user_defined_v<int> == false);
static_assert(is_user_defined_v<int*> == false);


Каким считать, например, vector<int>?

not (is_fundamental or is_pointer)

@Harry user-defined

@user7860670 а ссылки и константность

Для ссылок и константности уже есть соответствующие трейты для их отбрасывания.
